# How to remote to the computer itself with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, remoting

Now I need to run scripts on remote machines to do some deployment work by using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

And if the $hostName is the computer that calls this command, it reports:

```
message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (myMachineName:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I want to run the command in a unified way no matter it is a remote or the local machine.

Updated:
I'm using using a machine in Azure. this command works:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

But this one not:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX.cloudapp.net -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Write a helper commandlet that would wrap `Invoke-Command`, check for target computer and if it's the local one, don't pass the `-ComputerName` argument maybe?

Comment: maybe I missed something, but I can use invoke-command with the computer name as the computer that calls this command. I'm on version 3.0.

Comment: Thanks you n0rd and CB. I'm using a vm in Azure, and already updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `localhost` as the computer name:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Using the hostname of the computer should also work, as mentioned by @CB. in the comments to the question:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $cred `
  -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

If you need the FQDN elsewhere and just want to remove the domain part for the `Invoke-Command` statement you can remove it like this:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ($hostname -replace '\..*') -Credential $cred `
  -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

To handle the target computer name depending on whether or not the given hostname is the name of the local host you could do something like this:

```psh
$server = if (($hostname -replace '\..*') -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
            'localhost'
          } else {
            $hostname
          }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Note that either way WinRM must be enabled on the local computer for this to work.

Comment: Thank you, but in this way the caller needs first tell if it is localhost, just like this: if(is local machine) {invoke-command -computername localhost} else {invoke-command -computername $hostName} It's better to have unified way.

Comment: @TanJinfu Can you use just hostnames instead of FQDNs? What is the value of `$hostname`, and where does it come from?

Comment: $hostName is like 'XXX.cloudapp.net', but if not using FQDN, it can't remote to other Azure VMs.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar for the answer, but I have to remote to several machines including the current machine itself. So I have to tell if the machine is current machine (say, X) if different computer name is passed in, just like this: if(current machine is X){invoke-command -computerName localhost} else {invoke-command -computerName Y.cloudapp.net}. wondering why can't use FQDN to remote to itself.

Comment: Update the pseudo code: if($hostName is X){invoke-command -computerName localhost} else {invoke-command -computerName $hostName}.